# How to use jQuery's "closest" function with multiple toggles of same classes / id's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

Have tried a few different methods with no success, so am reaching out on here in hope someone can assist, I have scaled back the code below to it's most basic (and unfunctional form), basically what I need is I will have heaps of table rows the same way as shown below, but I want each checkbox action to trigger the toggle of the closest set of `<span>` items.

Code is below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input#change").change(function() {
    $("span.disabled").toggle();
    $("span.enabled").toggle();
    $("span.pending").toggle();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="page.php" method="post">

  <table>
    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="pending" style="display:none;">PENDING</span>
        <span class="disabled">DISABLED</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="statusArray[]" id="change" value="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Row 2 -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="pending" style="display:none;">PENDING</span>
        <span class="enabled">ENABLED</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="statusArray[]" id="change" value="2" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  </form>
```

The top code works if there is one row only, but I need it to handle multiple rows.

The checkbox will always be named `statusArray[]` and tagged as `#change`

There are 3 spans, though each row will only have two at any one time, these will be `span.enabled`, `span.disabled` and `span.pending`

Is there a way using jquery to activate the `toggle` only on the current table row? I need to figure out something that would achieve this.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: change ID to Class. if you're using ID it will only detect on first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this- made `#change` to class as multiple `id` are not possible.

Using `closest('tr')` to solve the issue- snippet below. Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input.change").change(function() {
    $this = $(this).closest('tr');   
    
    $this.find("span.disabled").toggle();
    $this.find("span.enabled").toggle();
    $this.find("span.pending").toggle();
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="page.php" method="post">
    <table>
      <!-- Row 1 -->
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span class="pending" style="display:none;">PENDING</span>
          <span class="disabled">DISABLED</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="statusArray[]" class="change" value="1" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Row 2 -->
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span class="pending" style="display:none;">PENDING</span>
          <span class="enabled">ENABLED</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="statusArray[]" class="change" value="2" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </form>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works well, exactly what I was trying to achieve, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not use duplicate `id` so use a `class` instead, or use `[name^=statusArray]`

If you are dynamically adding rows, then use a delegate.

You can use `closest` to find the row, then use `find` to `toggle`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('table').on('change', '[name^=statusArray]', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    row.find("span.disabled,span.enabled,span.pending").toggle();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <!-- Row 1 -->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="pending" style="display:none;">PENDING</span>
      <span class="disabled">DISABLED</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="statusArray[]" class="change" value="1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Row 2 -->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="pending" style="display:none;">PENDING</span>
      <span class="enabled">ENABLED</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="statusArray[]" class="change" value="2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){



$("input.change").change(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
```

$(this).parent("td").parent("tr").children("td").children("span.disabled").toggle();
          $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").children("td").children("span.enabled").toggle();
          $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").children("td").children("span.pending").toggle();

```
});

    });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form action="page.php" method="post">

<table>
    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="pending" style="display:none;">PENDING</span>
            <span class="disabled">DISABLED</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="statusArray[]" class="change" value="1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Row 2 -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="pending" style="display:none;">PENDING</span>
            <span class="enabled">ENABLED</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="statusArray[]" class="change" value="2" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Just change ID="change" to class="change" 
also $("input#change") to $("input.change")

and add $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").children("td").children to toggle to find the closest item from the class="change"

Comment: Couldn't get this one working, did you want to take a look again and edit it? 

Two other answers already worked for this, but if you wanted to correct this code into a working format I can upvote you for taking the time to answer :)